# How do i redirect back to a page after login for some pages?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to redirect back to some page like my pricing page after login in laravel but it redirect back to previous pages even the ones that I dont want it to redirect back to.

```
public function login()
{
    Session::put('url.intended',URL::previous());
    return view('login');
}
 public function loginPost()
 {
    if ($this->auth->attempt(array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password')))){
    return Redirect::to(Session::get('url.intended'));
}
return back();
}
```

Comment: Is this your controller code? If yes then what is this "return back();" line doing outside class function?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build login logic by yourself in laravel unless you want to , laravel provide pre-built auth scaffolding which you can use !

But what you are asking to redirect back for that you should use

```
return back();
```

At the ending of your function not at the ending of your class.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if ($this->auth->attempt(array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' =>  Input::get('password')))){
    if(!empty($request->session()->get('url.intended'))){
      return redirect($request->session()->get('url.intended'));
   }else{
     return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    
    }
 }
```